# Display the total number of bin elements in a stacked histogram with ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'd like to show data values on stacked bar chart in ggplot2. After many attempts, the only way I found to show the total amount (for each bean) is using the following code

```
set.seed(1234)

df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)

p<-ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, fill=sex, color=sex))
p<-p + geom_histogram(position="stack", alpha=0.5, binwidth=5)

tbl <- (ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]])[, c("x", "count")]
agg <- aggregate(tbl["count"], by=tbl["x"], FUN=sum)

for(i in 1:length(agg$x))
  if(agg$count[i])
    p <- p + geom_text(x=agg$x[i], y=agg$count[i] + 1.5, label=agg$count[i], colour="black" )
```

which generates the following plot:

[image]

Is there a better (and more efficient) way to get the same result using ggplot2?
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 6):

You can use `stat_bin` to count up the values and add text labels.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill=sex, color=sex), 
                 position="stack", alpha=0.5, binwidth=5) +
  stat_bin(aes(y=..count.. + 2, label=..count..), geom="text", binwidth=5)
```

I moved the `fill` and `color` aesthetics to `geom_histogram` so that they would apply only to that layer and not globally to the whole plot, because we want `stat_bin` to generate and overall count for each bin, rather than separate counts for each level of `sex`. `..count..` is an internal variable returned by `stat_bin` that stores the counts.

[image]

In this case, it was straightforward to add the counts directly. However, in more complicated situations, you might sometimes want to summarise the data outside of ggplot and then feed the summary data to ggplot. Here's how you would do that in this case:

```
library(dplyr)

counts = df %>% group_by(weight = cut(weight, seq(30,100,5), right=FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

countsByGroup = df %>% group_by(sex, weight = cut(weight, seq(30,100,5), right=FALSE)) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

ggplot(countsByGroup, aes(x=weight, y=n, fill=sex, color=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=0.5, width=1) +
  geom_text(data=counts, aes(label=n, y=n+2), colour="black")
```

Or, you can just create `countsByGroup` and then create the equivalent of `counts` on the fly inside `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(countsByGroup, aes(x=weight, y=n, fill=sex, color=sex)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=0.5, width=1) +
  geom_text(data=countsByGroup %>% group_by(weight) %>% mutate(n=sum(n)), 
            aes(label=n, y=n+2), colour="black")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. It's exactly what I was looking for. And thanks for the additional hints too